# Create an object in stateful widget's state that has a dependency on provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a class `Store` that is dependent on say class `Credentials` like

```
class Credentials {
  ...
}

class Store {
  ...
  Store(@required Credentials)
  ...
}
```

My stateful widget's build method uses things inside `Store` to generate the widget.
`Credentials` object is supplied via provider.

I have done this

```
@override
didChangeDependencies() {
  super.didChangeDependencies();
  Credentials creds = Provider.of<Credentials>(context);
  _store = Store(creds);
  ...
}
```

But is see _store recreated even when creds remain same.
(I can do a creds equality check and put creation of store inside it, but that to me seems just a fix). 
I just dont think this is the right approach. 
How do we solve this pattern in flutter gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how `Store` is used, you may either use `ProxyProvider`:

```dart
ProxyProvider<Credentials, Store>(
  builder: (_, creds, __) => Store(creds),
  child: ...,
)
```

or do an equality check of `Credentials` before creating a new `Store`:

```dart
Credentials credentials;
Store store;

@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  super.didChangeDependencies();
  final credentials = Provider.of<Credentials>(context);
  if (this.credentials != credentials) {
    this.credentials = credentials;
    store = Store(credentials);
  }
}
```